# How fix error in ixudra/curl in laravel with incorrect response

Tags: php, laravel, curl

My problem is as follows
Im trying to send request on 'https://api.hh.ru/areas/5' to get the response that you will see on the page that I indicated
Few hours im try to solved this problem but all the time i have the only mistake is:

```
"{"description":"Bad User-Agent header","errors":[{"value":"unset","type":"bad_user_agent"}],"request_id":"1585518015316eca42c25935194a7b01"}"
```

This is my code for request:

```
$response = Curl::to('https://api.hh.ru/areas/5')->withHeaders(array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'))->get();
```

Im use documentation from MDN to determine User Agent Headers
This is link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

If someone has information on how to solve this problem, I will be very grateful
Maybe somebody lnow another way to get this information
Im saved this file on my PC

Comment: My presumption would be they don't want their API used like this. I've never seen an API require a user agent.

Comment: Yes, I also did not see this
But maybe someone met a similar problem